# repeat random letter in string (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Working in python, Looking to create a function that takes a string and repeats a random letter within that string "n" amount of times. For example:

Input = "overflow"

function would return "overrflow" or "oveeerflow".

Dont really have any code so far besides splitting the string into an array.

Comment: Is ```n``` decided by the input or it is fixed?

Comment: Even if you have very little code, it is important to show what you have as a signal to the community that you are also putting effort into solving this problem.

Comment: What if that random letter appears in different places in the string? Should each one be duplicated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't we all love a little bit of Buddy Bob's homemade cookies.

```
import random
def multi(count,stringEx):
    randChar = random.choice(stringEx)
    amount = randChar * count
    return stringEx.replace(randChar,amount)
print(multi(3,'stackoverflow'))
```

First, select a random letter.

Multiply it by `count`.

use replace to add `amount` into `stringEx`.

output

```
stackoverflowww
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
import random

def repeat_random(n, input):
    random_char = input[random.randint(0,len(input)-1)]
    return input.replace(random_char, random_char*n)
```

> print(repeat_random(3, "overflow"))

> ovvverflow

Comment: `input` is a built-in function. Please use another name for your variables

Answer (score 1):

Try this?

```
import random
x=input("Word: ")  #=== Input for user
word=[d for d in x] #=== Create a list of every character in the string
rand=random.choice(word)  #==== Random choice of character from the list
index=word.index(rand) #=== Get the index position of the character
i=2
for n in range(i): #=== Iterate till i=2
    word.insert(index+n,rand) #=== add the random letter after the index position of similar letter

print("".join(word)) #=== Print the word by joining the characters
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like that:

```
from random import seed, randint

seed(42)

def repeat_letter(n, inp):
    pos = randint(0, len(inp))
    return inp[:pos]+inp[pos]*n+inp[pos+1:]


n = 3
inp = "overflow"
print(repeat_letter(n, inp))
print(repeat_letter(n, inp))
# ...
print(repeat_letter(n, inp))
```

The result is:

```
ovvverflow
oooverflow
overffflow
```